# IF Block in Markup to Change DataSource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've the following code in file test.aspx:

```
<% If (Session("username") <> "lok.dmt") Then%>
    <asp:dropdownlist id="id_loket"
        DataSource="<%# ModuleName.DefaultView %>"
        DataTextField="name_modul"
        DataValueField="id_modul"
        Width="385"
        runat="server"> </asp:dropdownlist>
<% Else%>             
    <asp:dropdownlist id="id_loket"
        DataSource="<%# ModuleNameDMT.DefaultView %>"
        DataTextField="name_modul"
        DataValueField="id_modul"
        Width="385"
        runat="server"> </asp:dropdownlist>           
<% End If%>
```

When I run the file, I got the following errors;

```
Parser Error Message: The ID 'id_loket' is already used by another control.
```

Comment: 1. ASP.NET is **NOT** Classic ASP.  What you have is ASP.NET.  2.  It looks like you're only changing the data source of the `DropDownList` - I don't know if you can do that the way you're trying.  You could, however, do it quite easily in the code-behind.

Comment: I'm new in ASP. It's true, I just want to change the data source conditionally, how to do that in ASP.net 2. Please help me

Comment: Try setting the data source in your Page_Load method.